# Animating a listview item takes effect on multiple rows

Tags: android, listview, animation, swipe

I'm having a strange issue. I need to implement swipe to delete in my listview. When user swipes left/right, I need to animate a delete button into/out of the screen and then on delete button click I need to delete that item from listview.

I am using Commonswares [TouchList] (https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist/tree/master/src/com/commonsware/cwac/tlv) library to achieve that. In onFling method it gets the position of the swiped row and send it to onRemove method in my activity. I can delete the item accurately. But if i animate the row at swiped position, multiple rows get effected. I am not able to fix this issue nor am I able to find any help.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this which was down to Android's view recycling.

(A good explanation of it is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works#answer-14108676))

To resolve I simply reset the animation in the item's OnResume method as I didn't need to retain the animation for the item which has scrolled out of view.